# Get rid of the ubuntu thing that suggests what packages you should install

Tags: ubuntu, bash, apt

I'm finding myself in the unfortunate place of using Ubuntu as a server OS and its tendency to suggest what packages I should install and how to install them when a program I enter in the shell isn't present is downright infuriating.  How do I get rid of this "feature?"

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/394153/what-causes-bash-to-pause-after-a-bad-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out (unsurprisingly) it's in /etc/bash.bashrc along with the equally patronizing sudo hint.  So you can just delete the offending lines and that fixes it.